# Quadrature Decoder Boolean Equation

Tags: vhdl, encoder, quartus

In order to implement a position counter from quadrature inputs, I used the following truth table:

[Similar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HC6L.png)

My Boolean equation (with Ap and Bp being the previous value of A and the previous value of B respectively) for Direction and Count/Movement can be seen below

```
Count <= (not Ap and not Bp and not A and B) or (not Ap and not Bp and A and not B) or 
     (not Ap and Bp and not A and not B) or (not Ap and Bp and A and B) or 
        (Ap and Bp and not A and B) or (Ap and Bp and A and not B) or 
     (Ap and not Bp and not A and not B) or (Ap and not Bp and A and B); -- complete boolean on conditions for a count value of 1

Direction <= (not Bp and A) or (Bp and not A); -- complete boolean on conditions for forward direction
```

One would expect the result to count up as long as B leads A

But instead all I get is this:

[Simulation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDi8D.jpg)

Any suggestions on what could be wrong? If my Boolean equation differs from your's please post it.

Comment: A `case` statement would make it easier to see if the truth table was implemented correctly.

Comment: Done that, still the same simulation result. What do I do?

Comment: A good start is to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); the simulation does not A and B, and the test bench code is not provided for readers to reproduce the problem.